# gitlab-ci How to Exec Mongo rs.initiate() after services running

Tags: mongodb, gitlab-ci

I want integration test for my GoLang project, and using mongodb transaction. to make it work. I need make mongodb services running replica set.

this my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: golang:1.13

services:
  - name: mongo:4.2
    alias: mongo-svc
    command: ["mongod", "--logpath=/dev/null", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet=rs0"]

unit_tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mongo-svc exec mongo --eval "rs.initiate()"
    - make test
```

i get error

```
$ mongo-svc mongo --eval "rs.initiate()"
 /bin/bash: line 95: mongo-svc: command not found
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I already use another command but still can't find how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Your .gitlab-ci.yml creates a mongo service (with a hostname alias of "mongo-svc") and then your script runs a command "mongo-svc".

There are two containers in play: mongo and golang.  Which container do you want to run the `mongo rs.initiate()` in?

(I know GitLab but not mongo, but I hope this helps a little.)

[Updated after reading your comment below and Kalyn Valentyn's reply in  https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-ci-how-to-exec-mongo-rs-initiate-after-services-running/36124]

The following `.gitlab-ci.yml` works:

```
image: golang:1.13

services:
  - name: mongo:4.2
    alias: mongo-svc
    command: ["mongod", "--logpath=/dev/null", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet=rs0"]


unit_tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - apt-get install -y gnupg
    - wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | apt-key add -
    - echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.2 main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y mongodb-org
    - mongo --host mongo-svc --eval "rs.initiate()"
```

Explanation:
- I install Mongo (per installation instructions at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/) -- first I had to identify that the golang image is based on Debian, which I did with `cat /etc/os-release` in the `script` section of the `unit_tests` job.
- Then I start the `mongo` shell on the golang image, point it at the mongo-svc host, and run `rs.initiate()`.

Here is the CI job log, showing success:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.9.0 (4c96e5ad)
   on docker-auto-scale 72989761
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
 Using Docker executor with image golang:1.13 ...
 Starting service mongo:4.2 ...
 Pulling docker image mongo:4.2 ...
 Using docker image sha256:c5e5843d9f5fd70b3c39d20c1c06478d067550c2dea667da1e4f1d777576a1f5 for mongo:4.2 ...
 Waiting for services to be up and running...
 Pulling docker image golang:1.13 ...
 Using docker image sha256:a80eb3fa71389ad9ecc1f615c274e8f76690fab74d03f5946c7443350308642c for golang:1.13 ...
Preparing environment
00:03
 Running on runner-72989761-project-17974064-concurrent-0 via runner-72989761-srm-1586454360-c1c2ce67...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
 $ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
 Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
 Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/atsaloli/mongo-test/.git/
 Created fresh repository.
 From https://gitlab.com/atsaloli/mongo-test
  * [new ref]         refs/pipelines/134529622 -> refs/pipelines/134529622
  * [new branch]      master                   -> origin/master
 Checking out abe63386 as master...
 Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache
Downloading artifacts
00:01
Running before_script and script
 $ apt-get install -y gnupg
 Reading package lists...
 Building dependency tree...
 Reading state information...
 gnupg is already the newest version (2.2.12-1+deb10u1).
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
 $ wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | apt-key add -
 Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
 OK
 $ echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.2 main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list
 deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.2 main
 $ apt-get update
 Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [65.4 kB]
 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [122 kB]
 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [49.3 kB]
 Ign:4 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.2 InRelease
 Get:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages [187 kB]
 Get:6 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.2 Release [1488 B]
 Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages [7907 kB]
 Get:8 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.2 Release.gpg [801 B]
 Get:9 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.2/main amd64 Packages [4083 B]
 Get:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages [7380 B]
 Fetched 8344 kB in 2s (3626 kB/s)
 Reading package lists...
 $ apt-get install -y mongodb-org
 Reading package lists...
 Building dependency tree...
 Reading state information...
 The following additional packages will be installed:
   mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
 The following NEW packages will be installed:
   mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell
   mongodb-org-tools
 0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
 Need to get 97.7 MB of archives.
 After this operation, 296 MB of additional disk space will be used.
 Get:1 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.2/main amd64 mongodb-org-shell amd64 4.2.5 [12.1 MB]
 Get:2 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.2/main amd64 mongodb-org-server amd64 4.2.5 [18.5 MB]
 Get:3 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.2/main amd64 mongodb-org-mongos amd64 4.2.5 [10.2 MB]
 Get:4 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.2/main amd64 mongodb-org-tools amd64 4.2.5 [57.0 MB]
 Get:5 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.2/main amd64 mongodb-org amd64 4.2.5 [3532 B]
 debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
 Fetched 97.7 MB in 2s (40.4 MB/s)
 Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-shell.
 (Reading database ... 15401 files and directories currently installed.)
 Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-shell_4.2.5_amd64.deb ...
 Unpacking mongodb-org-shell (4.2.5) ...
 Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-server.
 Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_4.2.5_amd64.deb ...
 Unpacking mongodb-org-server (4.2.5) ...
 Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-mongos.
 Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_4.2.5_amd64.deb ...
 Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (4.2.5) ...
 Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-tools.
 Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-tools_4.2.5_amd64.deb ...
 Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (4.2.5) ...
 Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org.
 Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org_4.2.5_amd64.deb ...
 Unpacking mongodb-org (4.2.5) ...
 Setting up mongodb-org-server (4.2.5) ...
 Adding system user `mongodb' (UID 101) ...
 Adding new user `mongodb' (UID 101) with group `nogroup' ...
 Not creating home directory `/home/mongodb'.
 Adding group `mongodb' (GID 102) ...
 Done.
 Adding user `mongodb' to group `mongodb' ...
 Adding user mongodb to group mongodb
 Done.
 Setting up mongodb-org-shell (4.2.5) ...
 Setting up mongodb-org-tools (4.2.5) ...
 Setting up mongodb-org-mongos (4.2.5) ...
 Setting up mongodb-org (4.2.5) ...
 $ mongo --host mongo-svc --eval "rs.initiate()"
 MongoDB shell version v4.2.5
 connecting to: mongodb://mongo-svc:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
 Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("3f798624-0569-423d-a8e1-03e84f9fee7f") }
 MongoDB server version: 4.2.5
 {
    "info2" : "no configuration specified. Using a default configuration for the set",
    "me" : "cf8a49d94069:27017",
    "ok" : 1,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1586455071, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1586455071, 1)
 }
Running after_script
00:02
Saving cache
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:02
 Job succeeded
```

Comment: i want run `mongo rs.initiate()` inside mongo container

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution

```
  services:
- name: mongo:latest
  alias: mongodb
  command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "mongod --fork --logpath /dev/stdout --bind_ip_all --replSet 'rs0' && mongo --eval 'rs.initiate(); rs.status()' > /dev/stdout && tail -f /var/log/*.log"]
```